# Facebook manage_pages

Tags: facebook, permissions

I develop helpdesk that imports posts from user's pages. But I need to have a manage_pages permission and manage_notifications. I created facebook app and set the permissions but thay have to be reviewed. Facebook wants to test the app how I use the imported posts. But how can I do that if I dont have the permission? Is there any way how to get this permission only for test ? I would like to implement this before ask facebook to review my app.

Thanks for all idea.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions work without review for everyone with a role in the App, of course you don´t need to go through the review process for testing.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer.